# Adding shadows to highlight overlapping elements in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, shadow

I am using `plot_surface` from `matplotlib` to generate a 3d-surface based on (X, Y, Z)-data in python. Unfortunately, for some data points it is quite difficult to differentiate the correct position in (x, y)-space due to an overlap with peaks before and behind, and a similar color due to similar values. This is shown in the figure below[image]
When comparing it with the 2d-plot the different peaks are clearly visible:
[image]
I could imagine that adding shadows might help, but I am not sure how to add shadows. My current code is (shortened down):

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={"projection": "3d"})
X_vals, T_vals = np.meshgrid(x_pos_vals[ylim_min:ylim_max], t_pos_vals[xlim_min:xlim_max])
surf = ax.plot_surface(X_vals, T_vals, np.abs(I_surf[xlim_min:xlim_max, ylim_min:ylim_max]), cmap=cm.inferno, linewidth=0, antialiased=False, cstride=1, rstride=1)
plt.show()
```

Adding artificial lighting helps a bit, changing the 3d-figure to [image]
by modifying the code to

```
ls = LightSource(azdeg=0, altdeg=65)
rgb = ls.shade(np.abs(I_surf[xlim_min:xlim_max, ylim_min:ylim_max]), plt.cm.inferno)
X_vals, T_vals = np.meshgrid(x_pos_vals[ylim_min:ylim_max], t_pos_vals[xlim_min:xlim_max])
surf = ax.plot_surface(X_vals, T_vals, np.abs(I_surf[xlim_min:xlim_max, ylim_min:ylim_max]), cmap=cm.inferno, linewidth=0, antialiased=False, cstride=1, rstride=1, facecolors=rgb)
```

but I am not sure if that is the best way to highlight the differences. Are there other ways of adding shadows/improve the visibility of the different features?

Comment: This is not reproducible. Please see [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Always provide a complete [mre] with **code, data, errors, current output, and expected output**, as **[formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)**. If relevant, only plot images are okay.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney: Without adding the data set which is responsible, is there any way to make the code/figures reproducible?

Comment: Anyone trying to answer your question, should be able to copy / paste your code and run it. It can use _synthetic data_, as long as it reproduces the issue in question, otherwise it is less likely (though not impossible) you will get an answer.